# Query by day and month range to fetch birthdays using Knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm looking to do a query by day and month range to fetch birthdays using knex.
Considering this interval (MM-dd) 03-28 and 04-03 get all data for birth interval month and day for all years.

```
const query = this.db("user_table")

let dayIni = format(sub(new Date(), { days: 7 }), "dd")
let dayEnd = format(new Date(), "dd")
let monthIni = format(sub(new Date(), { days: 7 }), "MM")
let monthEnd = format(new Date(), "MM")

query.whereRaw("EXTRACT(DAY FROM (user_table.birth)) >= ? AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (user_table.birth)) >= ?", [dayIni, monthIni])
query.whereRaw("EXTRACT(DAY FROM (user_table.birth)) <= ? AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (user_table.birth)) <= ?", [dayEnd, monthEnd])
```

Comment: Is this the month-day interval for all years or over the current year?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver edit question. All years

Answer (score 0):

Tentative answer. In raw SQL something like:

```
select 
 * 
from
   user_table
where 
     (extract(month from user_table.birth), extract(day from user_table.birth)) 
between (3, 28) and (4, 3)
```